# req.body will not return a response

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I've searched and tried other results, but none seem to render any results.

I'm trying to post data to the backend using postman as a test. The response is sending the 'success' message, but req.body returns an empty array every time I try. I'm using a node backend, with express and I'm trying to use routes. I've had success before, but for some reason I can't get it this time and my old code doesn't seem to work for this one. If I just log req, rather than req.body, I can see that the body is empty, the params are empty, but the url includes the params. I can post it, but it's rather long and I don't know if it's useful.

Here's the url I'm trying to hit: `localhost:3000/?testParam=test&test=boop`

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blogTest', { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const postsRoute = require('./routes/post');
app.use(postsRoute);

module.exports = app;
```

post.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const postModel = require('../models/post'); //not using this yet

router.get("/", function(req, res){
    console.log("Getting Posts...");
    postModel.find({}, function(err, posts){
        if(err){
            res.send("{'status': 'error', 'response': "+err+"}");
        }
        else if(posts.length < 1){
            res.send("{'status': 'null', 'response': {}}");
        }
        else{
            res.send("{'status': 'success', 'response': "+posts+"}");
        }
    });
});
router.post("/", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('success');
});
module.exports = router;
```

I'm expecting the console to log `{'testParam': 'test','test':'boop'}`
also, I've tried parsing req.body as json and stringifying it, but it causes the server to crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about http methods and how they work.

`req.body` is the POST request body, it is the data passed by the client when he sends a POST request to your api endpoint. If you are not sending any data in your POST request, then `req.body` will be empty.

In your example, to get the data from a request like `localhost:3000/?testParam=test&test=boop` you would need to look in `req.params` instead of `req.body`.

Comment: You're totally right - I realized that I input the data into the wrong part of postman. I put it in the body section and then it worked flawlessly. I'll accept your answer when the timer allows me to.

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to try accessing the params variable of the request by code, trying to go through a log to find params might not be accurate therefore try

```
router.post("/", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params);
    res.send('success');
});
```